# How to access <content:encoded> data from XML file in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, xpath

I am writing an rss feed with WPF and one of the feeds is a custom feed created by wordpress.  It has some data that is nested within an `<content:encoded>` tag that I want to get at, but I have been unable to.  I am trying to bind this data to some of my wpf controls.

some code:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="" XPath="//item" Source="" />
```

then I have a listbox where the source is bound to this static resource,
next I have a template that contains a number of controls that are bound to the xml data.

I can pull certain items from the xml file, i.e.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath="title"} />
```

works okay.  but now I want to access an `<img src="....png">` that is nested inside `<content:encoded>`.  XPath syntax like `Source={Binding XPath="content-encoded/img/@src"}`
doesn't work.

If you have any insight on how I can get at this part of the XML file it'd be great!

Comment: What are you using to pull some items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` is an XML namespace that needs to be [mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmlnamespacemappingcollection.aspx), here's an example from some RSS-reader sample i wrote:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <s:Uri x:Key="FeedUri">
        http://backend.deviantart.com/rss.xml?q=boost%3Apopular+max_age%3A8h&amp;type=deviation
    </s:Uri>
    <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection x:Key="NsMapping">
        <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="media" Uri="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"/> <!-- Slash at the end on dA for some reason... -->
        <XmlNamespaceMapping Prefix="atom" Uri="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
    </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" Source="{StaticResource FeedUri}"
                     XmlNamespaceManager="{StaticResource NsMapping}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- media and atom being used in a binding: -->
<Image Source="{Binding XPath=media:thumbnail/@url}" ToolTip="{Binding XPath=title}"/>
<Image Source="{Binding XPath=/rss/channel/atom:icon}" .../>
```

So with your mapping for `content` in place it should be: `{Binding XPath="content:encoded/img/@src"}`